# Couldn't run pyspark on windows cmd and conda cmd

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, conda

I have installed spark on my local system and it is working fine. However, I am not able to run pyspark in my system. Also, I did check the path and all details but nothing seems to work. Please help me with the issue.

**While running in conda cmd-**

```
    Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

    Warning:
    This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
    not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
    please see https://conda.io/activation
    
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
    Setting default log level to "WARN".
    To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
    22/01/19 20:15:04 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    22/01/19 20:15:05 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor). This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
    org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\shell.py:42: UserWarning: Failed to initialize Spark session.
      warnings.warn("Failed to initialize Spark session.")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 38, in <module>
        spark = SparkSession._create_shell_session()  # type: ignore
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 553, in _create_shell_session
        return SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
        sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 392, in getOrCreate
        SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 147, in __init__
        conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 209, in _do_init
        self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 329, in _initialize_context
        return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1574, in __call__
        answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
        format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
    : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
            at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
            at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
            at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
            at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
            at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
            at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

**While running on cmd**

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/01/20 14:32:41 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/01/20 14:32:42 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor). This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\shell.py:42: UserWarning: Failed to initialize Spark session.
  warnings.warn("Failed to initialize Spark session.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 38, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession._create_shell_session()  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 553, in _create_shell_session
    return SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 392, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 147, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 209, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 329, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1574, in __call__
    answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Any solution to this problem? Also, while closing spark (:quit) it is not able to close properly. Shows this error ShutdownHookManager: Exception while deleting Spark temp dir. java.io.IOException: Failed to delete:

Answer (score 1):

To activate an environment: `conda activate myenv`

Also,

> If you receive this warning, you need to activate your environment. To
> do so on Windows, run: c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base in Anaconda
> Prompt.
>
> Windows is extremely sensitive to proper activation. This is because
> the Windows library loader does not support the concept of libraries
> and executables that know where to search for their dependencies
> (RPATH). Instead, Windows relies on a dynamic-link library search
> order.

Comment: still not able to get the outcome. Can you please let me know any other approach available.